# Horizontal SingleChildScrollView position changes inside a ListView when scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout

I have a ListView with some items in it, including a SingleChildScrollView:

```
ListView(
  children: [
    SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      primary: false,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            // Container(height: 50, width: 200)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(height: 1000),
  ],
)
```

When I scroll all the way down and all the way up, the SingleChildScrollView has scrolled items all the way to the end on its own. I understand that ListView caches what it shows, but is it possible to preserve the scroll position of the SingleChildScrollView to whatever the user had scrolled it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am aware of two methods, once is increasing `cacheExtent` with `addAutomaticKeepAlives` value on `ListView`, another is using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`.

```dart
ListView(
  cacheExtent: 2122,// depend on your case
  addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
  children: [
    SingleChildScrollView(
      restorationId: "Scroll Item",
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
```

Second way is using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`,

```dart
class MyHorizontalListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHorizontalListView({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHorizontalListView> createState() => _MyHorizontalListViewState();
}

class _MyHorizontalListViewState extends State<MyHorizontalListView>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return SingleChildScrollView(
```

And place it on ListView. There might be some short way, idk,

Comment: Thank you so much! I use `flutter_hooks` package, so I am able to do this very easily by adding `useAutomaticKeepAlive(wantKeepAlive: true);` to my `build()`. Cheers!! !